# onDestroy() gets called when calling startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem returning from the GPS Settings. I want to check if GPS is enabled, but for some reasons not only onStop() gets called from the calling Activity, but also onDestroy and when I return from the Settings I arrive at the Main Screen as the Activity has been destroyed. I don't know what triggers this behavior as in another App the same Code works and returns. Its a simple call :

```
    case(GPS_SWITCHER):{
          Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS");
         //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
         startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

I tried working with the flags for the Intent but that did not solve it. I also tried calling the Intent from a PreferenceActivity, but already this call kills the Main app :-)
Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: I don't see a break in your switch case. Maybe you missed it and another case is executed, too?

Comment: post whole activity code. also override onDestroy() and put Log in it and debug it for behaviour of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `break;` in your `case` statement. That means the code immediately below is executed too.

Comment: Yes! Thank you thats silly ! I had a finish() call in the next Menu switch case and hence it was always called... It's easy to shoot yourself in the foot :-)

Comment: That's alright, that's one of the thing StackOverflow is for :)

Answer (score 5):

check if you write `noHisory="true"` in activity tag of Manifest file and remove it .
also check for other inappropriate parameter .